# How To Call OuterClass Method in a Wrapper Class

Tags: apex

I want to call outer class method in inner or wrapper class. How can we do it.

```
Public class t1{

public void method1(){

}

public class wt1{

////How to call method1 here in inner class.
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no automatic reference to the outer class provided in Apex (unlike non-static Java inner classes) so you need to pass in your own reference to the outer class and use that:

```
public class Outer {

    private Inner inner = new Inner(this);

    public void methodOuter() {
        ...
    }

    public class Inner {
        private Outer o;
        public Inner(Outer o) {
            this.o = o;
        }
        public void methodInner() {
            ...
            o.methodOuter();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```